# Python keyboard is unable to detect windows key

Tags: python, if-statement, keyboard

When using `if keyboard.is_pressed('win'):` nothing is returend,

I tried diffrent names for the windows key such as 'cmd', 'windows', 'leftwin'. I have also tried to see if it works to press the windows key and it does with the `keyboard.press_and_release('win')` command.

whole code:

```
import keyboard


while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('win'):
        print('p')
```

Comment: Looking at the defined modifiers example I think the key might be named `windows` per https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.KEY_DOWN

Comment: I tried with 'windows', and the only thing happening is the windows menu opening.

Comment: Try `keyboard.add_hotkey('windows', lambda: print('p'))`  though that is not really the way a lambda works

Answer (score 0):

The documentation at https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.KEY_DOWN suggests you might want:

```py
while True:
    keyboard.wait('windows')
    print('win was pressed! Waiting on it again...')
```

Or potentially

```py
def on_win():
    print('win was pressed')

keyboard.add_hotkey('windows', on_win)
```